# How can I create a 3 column table (ie a tile list) dynamically?

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following json-formatted data:

```
{"mydata": [{"phone":"5456868","name":"Dave"},{"phone":"9999875","name":"Susan"},
{"phone":"9994058","name":"Mary"},{"phone":"9995658","name":"Jan"},     
{"phone":"3584650","name":"Yanni"},{"phone":"4512523","name":"Wendy"},
{"phone":"6595959","name":"Jaime"}]}
```

I'd like to go through the data and create a tile-list starting at the top-left and working our way right (it's essentially a 3 column table):

```
  Dave -5456868   |  Susan-9999875  |   Mary -9994058 
  Jan  -9995658   |  Yanni-3584650  |   Wendy-4512523
  Jaime-6595959   |
```

I have the following (crude) attempt but it isn't very dynamic, nor does it add the closing  tag correctly...it should add  if it's the last entry for that row. Also, the number of entries in our json query will vary...we could get 1 result or 50...(it's not always going to be 7). thx!

```
function(data){
   $.each(data.mydata,function(i,user){

    if(i==0 || i==3 || i==6){
var tblRow="<tr>"+"<td>"+user.name+"-"+user.phone+"</td>";
}
if(i==1 || i==4 || i==7){
var tblRow="<td>"+user.name+"-"+user.phone+"</td>";
}
if(i==2 || i==5 || i==8){
var tblRow="<td>"+user.name+"-"+user.phone+"</td>"+"</tr>";
}
    $(tblRow).appendTo("#table> tbody");

});

      }
```

There's a number of SO questions regarding dynamic table generation, but the ones I've seen assume you have the same number of columns in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/4ed3L/2/)**. I used templates to replace the values inside the table/tr/td.

Comment: Again, this needs to be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using CSS to make it more flexible：

```
<style>
#resultTable ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#resultTable li {
    list-style:none;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}
#resultTable li div {
    border:1px solid #666666;
}
</style>

<div id="resultTable"></div>
<script>
var data = {"mydata": [{"phone":"5456868","name":"Dave"},{"phone":"9999875","name":"Susan"},
{"phone":"9994058","name":"Mary"},{"phone":"9995658","name":"Jan"},     
{"phone":"3584650","name":"Yanni"},{"phone":"4512523","name":"Wendy"},
{"phone":"6595959","name":"Jaime"}]}
function genTable(data){
    var contentData='';
    $.each(data.mydata,function(i,user){
        contentData += "<li><div>"+user.name+"-"+user.phone+"</div></li>";
    });
    $("#resultTable").html('<ul>'+contentData+'</ul>');
 }
genTable(data);
</script>
```